# Unable to mount volumes for pod

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, persistent-storage, openshift-origin

EDITED:
I've an OpenShift cluster with one master and two nodes. I've installed NFS on the master and NFS client on the nodes.
I've followed the wordpress example with NFS: https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/wordpress

I did the following on my master as: oc login -u system:admin:

```
mkdir /home/data/pv0001
mkdir /home/data/pv0002

chown -R nfsnobody:nfsnobody /home/data

chmod -R 777 /home/data/

# Add to /etc/exports
/home/data/pv0001 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/home/data/pv0002 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)

# Enable the new exports without bouncing the NFS service
exportfs -a
```

So exportfs shows:

```
/home/data/pv0001
        <world>
/home/data/pv0002
        <world>

$ setsebool -P virt_use_nfs 1


# Create the persistent volumes for NFS.
# I did not change anything in the yaml-files
$ oc create -f examples/wordpress/nfs/pv-1.yaml
$ oc create -f examples/wordpress/nfs/pv-2.yaml
$ oc get pv

NAME      LABELS    CAPACITY     ACCESSMODES   STATUS      CLAIM     REASON
pv0001    <none>    1073741824   RWO,RWX       Available             
pv0002    <none>    5368709120   RWO           Available
```

This is also what I get.
Than I'm going to my node:

```
oc login
test-admin
```

And I create a wordpress project:

```
oc new-project wordpress

# Create claims for storage in my project (same namespace).
# The claims in this example carefully match the volumes created above.
$ oc create -f examples/wordpress/pvc-wp.yaml 
$ oc create -f examples/wordpress/pvc-mysql.yaml
$ oc get pvc

NAME          LABELS    STATUS    VOLUME
claim-mysql   map[]     Bound     pv0002
claim-wp      map[]     Bound     pv0001
```

This looks exactly the same for me.

Launch the MySQL pod.

```
oc create -f examples/wordpress/pod-mysql.yaml
oc create -f examples/wordpress/service-mysql.yaml
oc create -f examples/wordpress/pod-wordpress.yaml
oc create -f examples/wordpress/service-wp.yaml

oc get svc
NAME            LABELS                                    SELECTOR         IP(S)            PORT(S)
mysql           name=mysql                                name=mysql       172.30.115.137   3306/TCP
wpfrontend      name=wpfrontend                           name=wordpress   172.30.170.55    5055/TCP
```

So actually everyting seemed to work! But when I'm asking for my pod status I get the following:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-104 pv0002]# oc get pod
NAME        READY     STATUS                                                              RESTARTS   AGE
mysql       0/1       Image: openshift/mysql-55-centos7 is ready, container is creating   0          6h
wordpress   0/1       Image: wordpress is not ready on the node                           0          6h
```

The pods are in pending state and in the webconsole they're giving the following error:

```
12:12:51 PM     mysql   Pod     failedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "mysql_wordpress": exit status 32 (607 times in the last hour, 41 minutes)
12:12:51 PM     mysql   Pod     failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: exit status 32 (607 times in the last hour, 41 minutes)
12:12:48 PM     wordpress   Pod     failedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "wordpress_wordpress": exit status 32 (604 times in the last hour, 40 minutes)
12:12:48 PM     wordpress   Pod     failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: exit status 32 (604 times in the last hour, 40 minutes)
```

Unable to mount +timeout. But when I'm going to my node and I'm doing the following (test is a created directory on my node):

```
mount -t nfs -v masterhostname:/home/data/pv0002 /test
```

And I place some file in my /test on my node than it appears in my /home/data/pv0002 on my master so that seems to work.
What's the reason that it's unable to mount in OpenShift?
I've been stuck on this for a while.

LOGS:

```
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 docker: time="2015-10-21T10:44:52.795267904Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/json"
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 origin-node: E1021 10:44:52.832179    1148 mount_linux.go:103] Mount failed: exit status 32
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 origin-node: Mounting arguments: localhost:/home/data/pv0002 /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/2bf19fe9-77ce-11e5-9122-02463424c049/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pv0002 nfs []
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 origin-node: Output: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/home/data/pv0002
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 origin-node: E1021 10:44:52.832279    1148 kubelet.go:1206] Unable to mount volumes for pod "mysql_wordpress": exit status 32; skipping pod
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 docker: time="2015-10-21T10:44:52.832794476Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/json?all=1"
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 docker: time="2015-10-21T10:44:52.835916304Z" level=info msg="GET /images/openshift/mysql-55-centos7/json"
Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 origin-node: E1021 10:44:52.837085    1148 pod_workers.go:111] Error syncing pod 2bf19fe9-77ce-11e5-9122-02463424c049, skipping: exit status 32
```

Comment: Check the node logs on the node hosting your pod - it's possible the volume mounter hit an error and returned early.

Comment: Also look for an event on the pod via oc describe pod/name - an event may have been fired.

Comment: The oc desribe pod/name gave the same output. Also the Unable to mount.. status 32. A manual mount is possible. Which logs? the /var/log/messages?

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of the log. I also changed the input with the more known wordpress-example. The issue remains the same.

Comment: Is it maybe something with the localhost in pv-1/2.yaml? I see something about that in the logs.

Comment: Okay, thanks clayton, you were right. The logs were a great help. It wanted to mount on 'localhost', but this had to be the master! So I had to change the pv-1/2.yaml for the server

Comment: @Anonymous I can see you have resolved this issue, can you post the solution as an answer and accept it. This will help others with the similar issue.

Comment: @Faizan done, sorry for the late reply

Comment: @lorenzvth7 thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logs showed `Oct 21 10:44:52 ip-10-0-0-129 origin-node: Output: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/home/data/pv0002`

So it failed mounting on localhost. 
to create my persistent volume I've executed this yaml:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "PersistentVolume",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "registry-volume"
  },
  "spec": {
    "capacity": {
        "storage": "20Gi"
        },
    "accessModes": [ "ReadWriteMany" ],
    "nfs": {
        "path": "/home/data/pv0002",
        "server": "localhost"
    }
  }
}
```

So I was mounting to `/home/data/pv0002` but this path was not on the localhost but on my master server (which is `ose3-master.example.com`. So I created my PV in a wrong way.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "PersistentVolume",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "registry-volume"
  },
  "spec": {
    "capacity": {
        "storage": "20Gi"
        },
    "accessModes": [ "ReadWriteMany" ],
    "nfs": {
        "path": "/home/data/pv0002",
        "server": "ose3-master.example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

This was also in a training environment. It's recommended to have a NFS server outside of your cluster to mount to.